# How to call DI Confgure<T>(Config) with reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, ioptionsmonitor

I have ASP.NET Core Web API.
I want to inject in DI container `IOptions<MySetting> options`. In `Startup` class it injected like this -
`services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySetting"));`. Where `MySettings` is class with some fields and a section with the same name in `appsetings.json`.

Also i want inject it with other way. With reflection:

```
var configureMethod = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions).GetMethods()
        .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MySettings));
```

I sure `configureMethod` matches with `services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySetting"));`.

But when I try to invoke this:

```
configureMethod.Invoke(null, new object?[] { services, configuration.GetSection("MySettings") });
```

I get error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerOptionService' for service type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerOptionService'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate()
...
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Where are you trying to invoke it? While configuring DI container? Could you please share the code?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev write in answers. Actually it was problem in searching types, not in calling method with reflection as i thought

Answer (score 0):

I tried add injecting with reflection for automatically registration `{featureNmae}Setting` classes in project, because there can be a lot of such classes in project.

In project i have many assemblies and i was getting them for suitable types with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` method.
Now i change it on `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` and it works!